# "Here's money, make my game"

Tags: game-industry

Okay I know it is not as easy as the title implies but I was wondering:
I have an idea of a game I want to play.
I recognize it would take a pretty huge development but for the full version I would be willing to pay up to €800, which I know does not cover the development costs in the slightest.

What are my options?

ps: I am not sure if this is the right stackexchange site but I couldn't find a better fit.

Comment: As has been brought up before, ideas are a dime a dozen. Your better off checking out forums or chat for this sort of thing, where to get started questions are off topic. Note that Stack Exchange does not cover everything. Questions of opinion, for example.

Comment: I know there is indeed a flood of idea's. My title in quote's was kind of mocking that problem. Tough a lot of people except game developers to just be super thrilled to be allowed to make their game idea. I know it's not like that but I was wondering if I want to make an actual demand incentive if there are any options to get a corresponding supply.

Comment: @turoni - because this is a discussion-oriented question it is really not suitable for this site (or for the SE platform, for that matter); SE is about questions and answers (and questions that have answers) rather than extended discussions.  You'll get more benefit on a site like gamedev.net

Comment: @LeComteduMerde-fou That seems like a good link and pretty much an answer to my question but I understand that there is no "one right answer" and thus probably not the correct place. But you got to start informing yourself somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 800 euros, unless you want a crappy freelanced game, you have a couple of options:

The best surefire way of doing it is to do it yourself, as Kerrigan Fairbairn said in his answer, because those 800 euros won't get you much more than a laptop, Unity, and freelanced artwork. The game could be a hobby of yours that you spend multiple years developing, heck, open source it and random people might help develop it! It be an amazing learning and developing experience that you'd be sure to enjoy after you lasso the basics.

If you truly believe that this is a great game idea and you do not have the time or expertise to spend 6 years working on it, your best bet will be Kickstarter. Use the 800 euros to get some fancy drawings and animations, then have a couple freelancers make you a great Kickstarter video. Using the remaining cash, rent out a studio for a night for the video to demonstrate the low risk. If you're successful, you have just converted those 800 euros into 350,000 USD. Now partner with a moderately sized game company depending on the scale of the game and, make a game!

Or, you could just wait till the AI uprising occurs and by a robot to make your game. :)

Comment: I don't really get all the downvotes but that seems like a valid strategy.
Tough I deem myself more successful at creating that AI than at creating this game myself :p

Comment: Just remember though, never trust an AI that's smarter than you.

Answer (score -1):

Your options are to pick up an accessible development kit like UE4 or Unity and learn how to use them to make the game yourself, then you can use the €800 to pay for freelance artwork or cheap licensing costs. Nobody is going to make a game of the scale you implied in your response for as little as €800.

Alternatively you can wait for a game that's similar to your idea to crop up on the open market coincidentally.

Answer (score -3):

Have you attempted using freelancers? They would most definitely be willing to work for cheap to make a game! Try using a website like freelance.com or upwork for higher end freelancers! Good luck and hire the right one!

Comment: My idea is of a pretty complicated MMO. I didn't want too describe the idea in too much detail since that was not what the question is about.
The game could not be implemented by a couple of freelancers.
It probably needs a company completely dedicated to that game.

Comment: You get what you pay for with 800 euros! Even a simple MMO would run you near 250k to 500k